# Codeigniter form validation error messages with bootstrap

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

I am new to `php codeigniter` framework. I am using basic form submission to submit data through a form. There is a form validation error showing function in `codeigniter framework`.
What I want to do is, when there is an error show it an a bootstrap popup or warning message. I tried so many ways but did not succeed. When I used bootstrap warning messages, I was unable to hide it when there was no error and in page load.
Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Add your code that you tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in codeigniter when you'r form is submitted , you can validation form elements like this :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('your element', ' ', 'trim|required');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
{
   $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Yor're data is not valid!');
}
```

and you can use up session in view for bootstrap alert like this :

```
<div style="margin-top: 8px" id="message">
           <?php
           if($this->session->userdata('message') != null)
           {
               echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">';
               echo '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>';
               echo $this->session->userdata('message') <> '' ? $this->session->userdata('message') : '';
               echo '</div>';
           }
           ?>
</div>
```

Comment: works like a charm. Even though I saw all these things, I couldn't gather them and fix my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Use `flashdata` to show your error messages

```
 $this->session->set_flashdata('flashSuccess', 'Leave Applied successfully');
 $this->session->set_flashdata('flashError', 'Some error found');
```

In your header add some code to display flash data

```
  <div class="container">
                <div class="row" id="flashMessage">
                    <?php
                    if ($this->session->flashdata('flashError')) {
                        ?>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                            <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                            <h4>Error!</h4>
                            <p><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('flashError'); ?>.</p>
                        </div> 
                        <?php
                    }
                    if ($this->session->flashdata('flashSuccess')) {
                        ?>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
                            <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                            <h4>Success!</h4>
                            <p><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('flashSuccess'); ?>.</p>
                        </div> 
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                </div>
            </div>
```